# 何も followed by a noun

Tags: grammar

I want to say "I don't know of any delicious restaurant.", and I'm not sure how to say this :

- 何も美味しいレストランを知りません.
- 美味しいレストランは一つも知りません.

But is it grammatically correct to put a noun after 何も ? which one sounds natural ?

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latter is more natural, although the former is understandable. 何も知らない and ひとつも知らない both roughly mean "to know nothing", but 何も知らない is usually about your knowledge about one particular topic. On the other hand, ひとつも知らない ("don't know even one") is about the number of items you know.

The position of 何も／ひとつも is flexible, and it can be either before or after 美味しいレストランは. The following sentences are equally fine.

- 美味しいレストランは一つも知りません。
- 一つも美味しいレストランは知りません。

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply it starting to be clear in my mind. Regarding the first sentence "何も美味しいレストランを知りません." can you confirm me that putting a noun after 何も is correct ? or is it strange ?

Comment: @Poulp 何もXを知らない and Xを何も知らない are both fine, but again, this is usually about one topic. For example 何も君のことを知らない and 君のことを何も知らない both mean "I know nothing about you".